# OpenGL Depth buffer "warped"

Tags: opengl, depth

I collect a depthbuffer from a scene. I notice however that when the camera and the scene's objects stay at the same position and the camera only rotates, the depthbuffer collects different results, e.g. an object shown on the side of the screen has different depth than when shown in the middle. This might be a feature of OpenGL, but even then, how can I correct for this? What to take in account?

I linearize my depth with the following function:

```
float linearize(float depth) {
    float zNear = 0.1;
    float zFar = 100.0;

    return (2.0 * zNear) / (zFar + zNear - depth * (zFar - zNear));
}
```

I checked the near and far values they're supposed to be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is to be expected. The perspective near plane is kind of the projection surface and the depth value is the distance of the point perpendicular to the depth plane. Now think about what happens if you rotate your "camera" (of course there's no camera in OpenGL): The perpendicular distance will vary by the sine of the rotation angle with some phase shift added.

If you want to actually measure the distance of the of the pixels to the viewpoint, then the best course of action would be not to use the depth buffer, but write a vertex shader, that passes the vertex distance to origin (builtin function `length`) as scalar to the fragment shader, and the fragment shader writes this into a single channel framebuffer object output.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion writing a vertexshader for this, I didn't know that could be an easy and yet complete solution.

Comment: What do I use as base for length? I have now ftransform * gl_Vertex, which comes close but isn't correct. Yes, I'm a newb..

Comment: @RobotRock: ftransform is just a little bit too much. You want the distance from the vertex position to the origin in eye space. Eye space is reached by multiplying the vertex position with *just* the modelview matrix (not the full transform which includes the projection).

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "camera" in OpenGL. When you change your modelview matrix (rotate the "camera"), you can actually think of moving the objects further or closer to the screen. That's why their rendered depth values will be different, since depth is calculated as normalized **transformed z of each vertex (fragment)**. Since after transformations you must take not only object's position, but also "camera" position into account, changing the modelview matrix changes the resulting z values.